# Trying to run another website on my Ubuntu 18 server

Tags: ubuntu, website, domain-name, configure

Currently, I'm running a website on my server called panel.0.net but I want to create a separate website on the server to take you to a page that says "Hello World" the way you'd get there is www.minenite.net

I tried adding a file called index.html in my /var/www/html folder but the www.0.net doesn't work.

How do I configure two separate sites to work one as panel. and one as www.

Also: using NGINX and everything is installed to run my other website as the panel. website

My friend said something about Name-Based Virtual Hosting?

Comment: Your friend is right

Comment: Can someone guide me on how I would set this Name-Based Virtual host up?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Show us your research.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. Used name-based virtual hosting.